# Loki not showing files from iPhone iOS 11.2.1

Tags: usb-drive, disk-management, mount, photos, iphone

I'm enjoying new install of elementary OS Loki. BUT, I need to access photos from an iPhone. I am connecting the iPhone using a USB 3.0 port in the back of a NUC. When I click "Trust this computer" on the phone, there is an icon for the iPhone under devices, but when I click on it, it says This Folder is Empty.

I saw someone else asked the same question in May but no answer yet, so I'm asking it again in hopes someone sees this who has a fix. Or is it not possible to access photos from an iPhone using elementary? I hate Windows and do not want to go back just for this issue.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there's no way to mount iOS devices on Linux anymore for some time. At least not any that I'm aware of. I just use icloud/apple photos to access my images.